# Google Cloud VM Files Deleted after Restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've restarted my VM instance and found that all of my files are deleted. My VM has a 10 GB SSD persistent boost disk and an additional 50GB SSD persistent disk. Do VM's only save files within the current session?

Thanks!

Comment: Disks and their contents are persistent. Review the console log to see what happened on restart: `gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output --zone us-east4-c INSTANCE_NAME > console.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google does not delete data upon restart. Be sure the disk containing your data is mounted. Perhaps you restarted after manually mounting & the disk is no longer mounted. You may have also been using the [cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features) instead of your VM which ["After the instance is terminated, any modifications that you made to it outside your $HOME are lost."](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) As per John Hanley's comment, you should also check the console log to see what happened on restart. Lastly, be sure you don't have any [start-up scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) that may have deleted data.